# Is there a reason that the text in my PDF is not appearing in the print preview on iOS?

Tags: ios, printing, uilabel, preview, airprint

Basically what is happening is I am constructing a PDF file from screenshots of the user's screen. The view contains a table view with text and icons.

Actually going through with the print process, everything renders correctly on paper.

HOWEVER, right before clicking the final "Print" button, the user sees the native iOS Print Preview screen. And on this PDF preview, the icons are rendered, but the labels are not.

My solution gets the job done, but it is a potentially confusing and frustrating experience for the user if they can't see an accurate preview of what they are trying to print.

```
func printPDF(pdf: Data) {
    if UIPrintInteractionController.canPrint(pdf) {
        let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
        printInfo.jobName = "Minutes"
        printInfo.outputType = .photo
        let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
        printController.printInfo = printInfo
        printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false
        printController.printingItem = pdf
        printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}

func generatePDF() -> Data {

    // Determine number of pages to create in PDF
    let contentHeight = Int(tableView.contentSize.height)
    let tableHeight = Int(tableView.frame.height)
    pageCount = (contentHeight/tableHeight) + 1

    var currentPage = 1
    pageOutlet.text = "Page \(currentPage)/\(pageCount)"

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.pdfContainerView.frame, nil)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    for _ in 0..<pageCount {

        // Update page number at bottom of screen
        pageOutlet.text = "Page \(currentPage)/\(pageCount)"

        // Create new page
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        pdfContainerView.layer.render(in: context!)

        // Adjust table view
        let originalYOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y
        let newOffset = originalYOffset + tableView.frame.height
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: newOffset)

        currentPage+=1  
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    return pdfData as Data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each label in the view, I had to set `isOpaque` to true, and set the background color of the labels to white.

I don't know exactly why this was happening, but I did manage to find the solution, so I thought I'd share.